# Computing Image Saliency via Neural Network Classifier

Tags: classification, tensorflow, gradient

Assume that we have a Convolutional Neural Network trained to classify (w.l.o.g. grayscale) images, in *Tensor-Flow*.

Given the trained net and a test image one can trace which pixels of it are salient, or "equivalently" which pixels are most responsible for the output classification of the image. A nice, explanation and implementation details in Theano, are given in this [article](https://github.com/Lasagne/Recipes/blob/master/examples/Saliency%20Maps%20and%20Guided%20Backpropagation.ipynb).

Assume that for the first layer of convolutions that is directly linked with the input image, we do have the gradient for the parameters of every convolutional kernel-wrt. the classification function.

**How can one propagate the gradient back to the Input layer, so to compute a partial derivative on every pixel of the image?**

1. Propagating and accumulating back the gradient, would give us the salient pixels (they are those with big in-magnitude derivative).
2. To find the gradient wrt. the kernels of the first layer, so far I did:

   1. Replaced the usual loss operator with the output layer operator.
   2. Used the "compute_gradient" function,

All in all, it looks like:

- opt         = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1)
- grads        = opt.compute_gradients(output)
- grad_var     = [(grad[1](https://github.com/Lasagne/Recipes/blob/master/examples/Saliency%20Maps%20and%20Guided%20Backpropagation.ipynb)) for grad in grads]
- g1           = sess.run([grad_var[0]])

Where, the "output" is the max of the output layer of the NN. 
And g1, is a (k, k, 1, M) tensor, since I used M: k x k convolutional kernels on the first layer.

Now, I need to find the correct way to propagate g1 on every input pixel, as to compute their derivative wrt. the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compute the gradients, you don't need to use an optimizer, and you can directly use [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#gradients).
With this function, you can directly compute the gradient of `output` with respect to the image `input`, whereas the optimizer `compute_gradients` method can only compute gradients **with respect to Variables**.

The other advantage of `tf.gradients` is that you can specify the gradients of the output you want to backpropagate.

---

So here is how to get the gradients of an input image with respect to `output[1, 1]`:

- we have to set the output gradients to `0` everywhere except at indice `[1, 1]`

```py
input = tf.ones([1, 4, 4, 1])
filter = tf.ones([3, 3, 1, 1])
output = tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, [1, 1, 1, 1], 'SAME')

grad_output = np.zeros((1, 4, 4, 1), dtype=np.float32)
grad_output[0, 1, 1, 0] = 1.

grads = tf.gradients(output, input, grad_output)

sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(grads[0]).reshape((4, 4))
# prints [[ 1.  1.  1.  0.]
#         [ 1.  1.  1.  0.]
#         [ 1.  1.  1.  0.]
#         [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```