# How to compute the gradient of an image based on a certain class?

Tags: image, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

In the [Breaking Linear Classifiers on ImageNet](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/03/30/breaking-convnets/), the author proposes the following way to create adversarial images that fool ConvNets:

> In short, to create a fooling image we start from whatever image we
>   want (an actual image, or even a noise pattern), and then **use
>   backpropagation to compute the gradient of the image pixels on any
>   class score**, and nudge it along. We may, but do not have to, repeat
>   the process a few times. You can interpret backpropagation in this
>   setting as using dynamic programming to compute the most damaging
>   local perturbation to the input. Note that this process is very
>   efficient and takes negligible time if you have access to the
>   parameters of the ConvNet (backprop is fast), but it is possible to do
>   this even if you do not have access to the parameters but only to the
>   class scores at the end. In this case, it is possible to compute the
>   data gradient numerically, or to to use other local stochastic search
>   strategies, etc. Note that due to the latter approach, even
>   non-differentiable classifiers (e.g. Random Forests) are not safe (but
>   I haven’t seen anyone empirically confirm this yet).

I know I can calculate the gradient of an image like this:

```
np.gradient(img)
```

But how do I compute the gradient of an image relative to another image class using TensorFlow or Numpy? Probably I need to do something similar to the process [in this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/pros/)? Such as:

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_conv, y_))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for i in range(20000):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
  if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

But I'm not sure exactly how...Specifically, I have an image of digit 2 as below:
[image]

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.14117648,  0.49019611,  0.74901962,
         0.85490203,  1.        ,  0.99607849,  0.99607849,  0.9450981 ,
         0.20000002,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.80000007,  0.97647065,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,
         0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,
         0.98039222,  0.92156869,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.34509805,
         0.9450981 ,  0.98431379,  0.99215692,  0.88235301,  0.55686277,
         0.19215688,  0.04705883,  0.04705883,  0.04705883,  0.41176474,
         0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.43529415,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.37254903,  0.88235301,
         0.99215692,  0.65490198,  0.44313729,  0.05490196,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.0627451 ,
         0.82745105,  0.99215692,  0.45882356,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.35686275,  0.9333334 ,  0.99215692,
         0.66666669,  0.10980393,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.58823532,  0.99215692,  0.45882356,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.38431376,  0.98431379,  0.85490203,  0.18823531,
         0.01960784,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.58823532,  0.99215692,  0.45882356,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.43921572,  0.99215692,  0.43921572,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.03529412,
         0.72156864,  0.94901967,  0.07058824,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.07843138,  0.17647059,  0.01960784,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.26274511,
         0.99215692,  0.94117653,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.10588236,  0.91764712,
         0.97254908,  0.41176474,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.17254902,  0.6156863 ,  0.99215692,
         0.51764709,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.04313726,  0.74117649,  0.99215692,  0.7960785 ,
         0.10588236,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.04313726,  0.61176473,  0.99215692,  0.96470594,  0.3019608 ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.04313726,
         0.61176473,  0.99215692,  0.79215693,  0.26666668,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.04313726,  0.61176473,
         0.99215692,  0.88627458,  0.27843139,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.11764707,  0.12941177,
         0.12941177,  0.54901963,  0.63921571,  0.72941178,  0.99215692,
         0.88627458,  0.14901961,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.04705883,  0.31764707,  0.95686281,  0.99215692,
         0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,
         0.99215692,  0.72941178,  0.27450982,  0.09019608,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.08627451,  0.61176473,  0.3019608 ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.3137255 ,  0.76470596,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,
         0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.97254908,  0.91764712,  0.65098041,
         0.97254908,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.94117653,  0.58823532,
         0.28627452,  0.56470591,  0.40784317,  0.20000002,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.02745098,
         0.97254908,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,
         0.99215692,  0.94901967,  0.41176474,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.41960788,  0.94901967,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,
         0.96078438,  0.627451  ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.22352943,
         0.98039222,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.99215692,  0.96862751,
         0.52941179,  0.08235294,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.08235294,  0.45882356,  0.71764708,  0.71764708,
         0.18823531,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.47450984,  0.48235297,  0.6901961 ,  0.52941179,  0.0627451 ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]], dtype=float32)
```

How do I compute the gradient of this image relative to the the digit 6 image class (with an example shown below)? (I guess I need to compute the gradient for all digit 6 images using back propagation.)
[image]

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.19215688,  0.70588237,  0.99215692,
         0.95686281,  0.19607845,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.72156864,  0.98823535,  0.98823535,
         0.90980399,  0.64313728,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.25882354,  0.91764712,  0.98823535,  0.53333336,
         0.14901961,  0.21960786,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.07450981,  0.92549026,  0.98823535,  0.6901961 ,  0.01568628,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.29803923,  0.98823535,  0.98823535,  0.21960786,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.54509807,  0.99215692,  0.67843139,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.08627451,
         0.83137262,  0.98823535,  0.27058825,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.45490199,
         0.99215692,  0.94117653,  0.19607845,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.6156863 ,
         0.99215692,  0.80784321,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.90196085,
         0.99215692,  0.40000004,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.90588242,
         1.        ,  0.70588237,  0.5411765 ,  0.70588237,  0.99215692,
         1.        ,  0.99215692,  0.8705883 ,  0.38039219,  0.01176471,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.90196085,
         0.99215692,  0.98823535,  0.98823535,  0.98823535,  0.98823535,
         0.82745105,  0.98823535,  0.98823535,  0.98823535,  0.45882356,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.90196085,
         0.99215692,  0.94117653,  0.71764708,  0.34901962,  0.27058825,
         0.02745098,  0.27058825,  0.67058825,  0.98823535,  0.98823535,
         0.33333334,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.52941179,
         0.99215692,  0.60000002,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.0509804 ,  0.84313732,  0.98823535,
         0.45490199,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.45490199,
         0.99215692,  0.80784321,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.60784316,  0.98823535,
         0.45490199,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.41568631,
         1.        ,  0.82745105,  0.02745098,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.19215688,  0.91372555,  0.99215692,
         0.45490199,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.62352943,  0.98823535,  0.60392159,  0.03529412,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.11764707,  0.77254909,  0.98823535,  0.98823535,
         0.37254903,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.06666667,  0.89019614,  0.98823535,  0.60392159,  0.27450982,
         0.31764707,  0.89411771,  0.98823535,  0.89019614,  0.50980395,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.19607845,  0.89019614,  0.98823535,  0.98823535,
         0.99215692,  0.98823535,  0.72549021,  0.19607845,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.18823531,  0.7019608 ,  0.98823535,
         0.74509805,  0.45882356,  0.02352941,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]], dtype=float32)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here're two related questions that I asked:

[How to use image and weight matrix to create adversarial images in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966589/how-to-use-image-and-weight-matrix-to-create-adversarial-images-in-tensorflow)

[How to create adversarial images for ConvNet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308181/how-to-create-adversarial-images-for-convnet)

And here's [my script](https://github.com/georgeliu1998/deep-learning/blob/master/adversarial_images/adversarial_images.ipynb).

Comment: What do you mean by "gradient of an image relative to some other image"? Do you mean the difference between the two? Do you mean just the gradient of the image?

Comment: @chris_anderson  I mean exactly the same as in the quoted article "use backpropagation to compute the gradient of the image pixels on any class score". Thanks!

Comment: You can only compute the gradient of a function. For instance, if the function maps images (input) to a vector of class scores (output), you can compute the gradient of the output with respect to the input. But here you say you want to compute the gradient of an image with respect to another image, and you would need a function mapping images to images to do that. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38118074/5098368) might help you understand.

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot you can also compute the gradient of an image - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient. I guess I was wondering if he was talking about that.

Comment: @GeorgeLiu: The tensorflow tutorial on deep dreaming has an example of taking the gradient of an image with respect to some layer. Specifically [this section] (https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/deepdream/deepdream.ipynb#Naive-feature-visualization) should be helpful (ie t_grad = tf.gradients(t_score, t_input)[0]). Note: the blog you quote is not taking a gradient of one image relative to another image. It is taking the gradient of an image relative to class scores. And wrt deep dreaming, class scores are just another layer.

Comment: this link has a video on adversarial network and an example that is well documented. https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials

Comment: @chris_anderson the output of a classifier neural net is typically a vector with one element per class where each element is (effectively) an approximation to the probability that the input image is of that class (or which minimizes the log loss on the training images). Give a cats vs dogs classifier network, a cat image might produce an output (0.9, 0.1) or 90% cat.  The gradient that this question asks about is the pixels of the input image with respect to one of the elements of the network output  (class probabilities).  It is not the gradient of an image wrt spatial coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

### Class scores only

If you only have access to class scores for any image you suggest there's not much fancy you can do to truly compute a gradient.

If what is returned can be seen as a relative score for each category it is a vector `v` that is the result of some function `f` acting on a vector `A` that contains all the information on the image*. The true gradient of the function is given by the matrix `D(A)`, which depends on `A`, such that `D(A)*B = (f(A + epsilon*B) -f(A))/epsilon` in the limit of small `epsilon` for any `B`. You **could** approximate this numerically using some small value for epsilon and a number of test matrices `B` (one for each element of `A` should be enough), but this is likely to be needlessly expensive.

What you are trying to do is maximize the difficulty the algorithm has in recognizing the image. That is, for a given algorithm `f` you want to maximize some appropriate measure for how poorly the algorithm recognizes each of your images `A`. There is a plethora of methods for this. I'm not too familiar with them, but a talk I saw recently had some interesting material on this (https://wsc.project.cwi.nl/woudschoten-conferences/2016-woudschoten-conference/PRtalk1.pdf, see page 24 and onwards). Computing the whole gradient is usually way too expensive if you have high dimensional input. Instead you just modify a randomly chosen coordinate and take many (many) small, cheap steps each more or less in the right direction rather than going for somehow optimal large, but expensive steps.

### Model available and suitable

If you know the model in full and it is possible to write is explicitly as `v = f(A)` then you can compute the gradient of the function `f`. This would be the case if the algorithm you're trying to beat is a linear regression, possibly with multiple layers. The form of the gradient should be easier for you to figure out than for me to write it down here.

With this gradient available and fairly cheap to evaluate its value for different images `A` you can proceed with, for example, a steepest descent (or ascent) approach to making the image less recognizable for the algorithm.

### Important note

It's probably best not to forget that your approach should not render the image illegible to humans too, that would make it all rather pointless.

- I think for the purpose of this discussion it's best to see the image as a vector